# «Земля прощается голубым светом» — можно так писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Земля уплывает, прощается голубым светом, отпуская нас.

Может ли Земля прощаться светом? Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно найти аналогии (проститься/прощаться чем-либо):

> «Зима **прощается яркими звездами**, весна приходит сухими тропинками. [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1922)]
>
> Долго не стал упрашивать, и хотя она обещала позже, просила подождать ― **простился холодным рукопожатием** и пришел снова только на другой день. [В. Н. Гельфанд. Дневники 1944-1946 гг. (1944-1946)]
>
> Наконец в начале июля налетевшая с востока буря хотя и засыпала все снегом, но разломала лед, и судно, давно уже обколотое, готовое к плаванию, **простилось салютом** с печальной Землей Нансена и направилось на юг. [В. А. Обручев. Плутония (1924)]
>
> должно было **проститься поклоном**, при опасном свидетеле, задавить слезу улыбкою, задушить вздохи приветами, желать счастья, нося ад в груди своей. 
>   [А. А. Бестужев-Марлинский. Фрегат «Надежда» (1833)]
>
> Он снова **прощался взглядом** с женой. ― Хорошо, хорошо! [Артем Тарасов. Миллионер (2004)]

Однако "Земля прощается голубым светом" уместно лишь при условии, что голубой свет связан именно с моментом расставания с Землей (виден короткое время "на прощание"), а так ли это, надо бы спросить у астрофизиков.

Comment: Примеры из старых текстов. Может быть, УСТАРЕВШАЯ (а не новая) грамматика? Кстати, (для сравнения) в приводимых здесь выражениях встретить, проводить дождем  глагол переходный (кого? чем?), а глагол прощаться - возвратный, прощаются с кем/чем и  чем?

Answer (score 5):

***Земля уплывает, прощается голубым светом, отпуская нас.***

Я думаю, что это авторский грамматический окказионализм, индивидуально-авторское сочетание *прощаться (чем?) светом.*

Из словаря:

**ПРОСТИТЬСЯ, 1**. (с кем). Обменяться рукопожатием, словами привета и т.п. при расставании с кем-л. Ушёл, не простясь. П. перед разлукой. 2. с чем (кем). **Оставить, покинуть что-л., расстаться надолго, навсегда**. **П. с родными местами**.

Как мы видим, прощаться (чем?) — **ненормированное сочетание**. Можно сказать: *дарит на прощание голубой свет,* но такое "банальное, обыкновенное" выражение, вероятно, не вписывается в стилистику автора.

Поэтому нельзя говорить о грамматической правильности, здесь ее нет, но есть художественный прием (а насколько удачный, это судить читателю).

Comment: Проститься (*чем?*) - периодически используемая в литературе форма. Попробуйте поискать в Гугле "простился кивком головы" или другие подобные сочетания.

Comment: Может быть, и используемая, но ненормированная, с ограниченными возможностями. Можно еще как-то принять "проститься кивком головы", но проститься, к примеру,  "пожатием руки, прикосновение руки" - это уже из области свободной грамматики (как нравится, так и пишу). Сюда же можно отнести "проститься светом", только это еще и метафора. Для невзыскательного читателя  самиздата, может быть,  и нормально.  Сейчас много такой литературы.

Comment: Лично мне метафора "Земля прощается голубым светом" показалась достаточно удачной. Хотя тут, конечно, вопрос вкуса. В любом случае, Ваш подход тоже имеет право на жизнь, именно поэтому я вчера добавил Вашем ответу мой голос "за".

Comment: Особая грамматика и использование метафор - это выбор автора, художественные средства должны соответствовать общему стилю произведения.  Но вот автор вопроса  должен понимать значение слова "правильно". Правильность - это соответствие нормам речи, но иногда "неправильность" тоже может являться средством художественной выразительности.

Comment: @Ivan Olshansky "Проститься жестом" имеет иной смысл ("посредством чего?"), чем напр. "встретить хорошей погодой" (она просто "наблюдалась" в той же местности в соотв. момент; для "встречи" это обычное выражение). Здесь нужно рассматривать на предмет корректности выражение "проводить дождём": оно выглядит приемлемым, но сомнение вызывает возможность его обобщения на прочие явления (вроде _синего света_) при прощании.

Comment: @Alex_ander, тут очень тонкая грань. Все зависит от того, какую степень авторской свободы считать допустимой.

Answer (score 2):

Может.
При прохождении через земную атмосферу, солнечный свет приобретает голубой оттенок. Соответственно, именно такой отражаемый Землей свет будет видеть наблюдатель, отделившийся от Земли и оставшийся неподвижным относительно Солнца в точке разделения, когда он будет наблюдать, как Земля удаляется от него, двигаясь по своей орбите.
Ну а прощается Земля этим светом или просто его отражает - так это кому как видится...

Answer (score 0):

Обычно тот, кто "отпускает", тот неподвижен, а у вас Земля уплывает. Тогда прощаться с ней должны мы.

Comment: Для космонавта, улетающего от Земли на космическом аппарате, Земля будет видеться уплывающей. И возможно даже прощающейся с ним.